# Using Remote Assistance (mstsc) on remote Windows 8.1 computer needs to enter twice login / password

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-assistance

I'm connecting to multiple Windows 8.1 computer using mstsc (Remote assistance). These computers belong to the same active directory than my laptop (Windows 10) where I launch mstsc.

On most of these computers, I need to enter my credentials twice :

1. One by Windows Laptop
2. Another one and the remote computer, just like if the computer was locked.

Do you know any parameter that can be set to avoid this double login ?

Answer (score 0):

On host computer, navigate to group policy path `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security` and disable `Always prompt for password upon connection`. Then on client computer go to `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client` and `disable Prompt for credentials` on the client computer and `Do not allow passwords to be saved`. Then run `gpupdate /force`.

HTH

Comment: The three parametres were "not configured". After setting them to disabled, I still have the same issue (entering login twice) :(

Comment: @nmariot, This simply will not work on windows 8.1, I know because I have tried.